# Get generic parameters of a generic type

Tags: java, generics, reflection, nested-generics

For some background, I'm working on some framework stuff for a programming language I'm developing (JVM language, that is), and was testing some of the framework with Java classes, hence all the weird wrappers below.

---

So, my questions is, how do I get the type variables of a type parameter's bounds? Currently I have the following:

```
public static TemplateGenerics of(Class clazz) {
    TemplateGenerics generics = new TemplateGenerics(); //TemplateGenerics is a wrapper class for generics that appear in the class header
    Stream.of(clazz.getTypeParameters()).forEach(typeVariable -> {
        java.lang.reflect.Type b = typeVariable.getBounds()[0];
        try {
            Class c = Primitives.resolveClass(b.getTypeName().split("<", 2)[0]); //Is there a better way to do this?
            TemplateGenerics sub = TemplateGenerics.of(c); //Recursivley get the generics - it fails here
            generics.getConditionals().add(new Conditional(new Type.Hierarchical(sub, c.getName()), Conditional.Condition.EXTENDS, typeVariable.getName())); //Conditional is another wrapper class that handles bounds of the generic, 
                                                                                                                                                             //Type.Hierachical is yet another wrapper class that wraps types that appear in class headers
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); //For testing purposes
        }
    });
    return generics;
}
```

But this fails with a StackOverflowException when it encounters something like this:

`public class A<T extends A<T>> ...`

Since it just continues trying to get the type parameters of A over and over. I've been unable to find a method of getting the type variable's type variables... I've tried messing around with getGenericDeclaration, but it does not seem to return what I need. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should also consider case `A<T extends B<T>>` and `B<T extends A<T>>`. Generally to avoid cycles you should keep already processed and currently processed types. If you encounter type that you start to processing but not end you should use some placeholder and then after you process all types you should replace placeholders by proper results

Comment: Yeah, I tried to do something like that with a map, but I'm still not exactly sure how to get the information I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*@csharpfolk* was right to suggest keeping a tally of what has already been parsed and making leverage of that. Below is a compile & runnable example which demos what this looks like in practice for your problem.

```
package so.answers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class TemplateGenerics {

    private final List<Conditional> conditionals = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Conditional> getConditionals(){
        return conditionals;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return getConditionals().toString();
    }

    public static TemplateGenerics of(Class<?> clazz) {
        return TemplateGenerics.of(clazz, new HashMap<>());
    }

    private static TemplateGenerics of(Class<?> clazz, Map<Class<?>, TemplateGenerics> existingGenericsForClasses) {
        if(existingGenericsForClasses.containsKey(clazz)){
            return existingGenericsForClasses.get(clazz);
        }
        final TemplateGenerics generics = new TemplateGenerics();
        existingGenericsForClasses.put(clazz, generics);

        Stream.of(clazz.getTypeParameters()).forEach(typeVariable -> {
            java.lang.reflect.Type b = typeVariable.getBounds()[0];
            try {
                Class<?> c = Primitives.resolveClass(b.getTypeName().split("<", 2)[0]); //Is there a better way to do this?
                TemplateGenerics sub = TemplateGenerics.of(c, existingGenericsForClasses); //Recursivley get the generics - it fails here
                generics.getConditionals().add(new Conditional(new Type.Hierarchical(sub, c.getName()), Conditional.Condition.EXTENDS, typeVariable.getName())); //Conditional is another wrapper class that handles bounds of the generic, 
                                                                                                                                                                 //Type.Hierachical is yet another wrapper class that wraps types that appear in class headers
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e); //For testing purposes
            }
        });
        return generics;
    }

    public static class Conditional{
        public static enum Condition{
            EXTENDS,
            SUPER
        }

        private final Type.Hierarchical hierarchical;
        private final Condition condition;
        private final String typeName;

        public Conditional(Type.Hierarchical hierarchical, Condition condition, String typeName){
            this.hierarchical = hierarchical;
            this.condition = condition;
            this.typeName = typeName;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return "Conditional$typeName="+typeName+" "
                    +"Conditional$condition="+condition+" "
                    +"Conditional$hierarchical={"+hierarchical+"} ";                    
        }
    }

    public static class Primitives{
        public static Class<?> resolveClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException{
            String trimmedName = name.replaceFirst(TemplateGenerics.class.getCanonicalName()+".", "");

            //not sure why this nonsense with the trimmed name
            //is necessary, but you seem to already have a better
            //version of this method anyway
            if(trimmedName.contains(TemplateGenerics.class.getCanonicalName())){
                name = trimmedName;
            }
            return Primitives.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(name);
        }
    }

    public static class Type{
        public static class Hierarchical{
            private TemplateGenerics generics;
            private String name;

            public Hierarchical(TemplateGenerics generics, String name){
                this.generics = generics;
                this.name = name;
            }


            private boolean printing;

            public String toString(){
                try{
                    if(!printing){
                        printing = true;
                        return "Hierarchical$name="+name+ " Hierarchical$generics=("+generics+")";
                    } else {
                        return "Hierarchical$name="+name;
                    }
                } finally {
                    printing = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class B{

    }

    public static class C<T extends B>{

    }

    public static class A<T extends A<T>>{

    }

    public static class X<T extends Y>{

    }

    public static class Y<T extends X>{

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("For A:"+TemplateGenerics.of(A.class));
        System.out.println("For C:"+TemplateGenerics.of(C.class));
        System.out.println("For X:"+TemplateGenerics.of(X.class));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
For A:[Conditional$typeName=T Conditional$condition=EXTENDS Conditional$hierarchical={Hierarchical$name=so.answers.TemplateGenerics$A Hierarchical$generics=([Conditional$typeName=T Conditional$condition=EXTENDS Conditional$hierarchical={Hierarchical$name=so.answers.TemplateGenerics$A} ])} ]
For C:[Conditional$typeName=T Conditional$condition=EXTENDS Conditional$hierarchical={Hierarchical$name=so.answers.TemplateGenerics$B Hierarchical$generics=([])} ]
For X:[Conditional$typeName=T Conditional$condition=EXTENDS Conditional$hierarchical={Hierarchical$name=so.answers.TemplateGenerics$Y Hierarchical$generics=([Conditional$typeName=T Conditional$condition=EXTENDS Conditional$hierarchical={Hierarchical$name=so.answers.TemplateGenerics$X Hierarchical$generics=([Conditional$typeName=T Conditional$condition=EXTENDS Conditional$hierarchical={Hierarchical$name=so.answers.TemplateGenerics$Y} ])} ])} ]
```

You could clean up the printing to look a little less redundant by printing the type rather than the generics directly. But this shows all the salient features of the solution.

Comment: Thanks very much! That's basically identical to what I ended up doing.